# Selecting elements in DataFrame array in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, slice, data-manipulation

I have a file with customer address data that needs to be loaded and cleansed with Databricks. There is a column that contains the Suburb/City as well as the State and Country code. I need to split these into their three respective values.

| CityStateCountry |
| --- |
| BRISBANE QLD AU |
| BRISBANE WEST QLD AU |
| SOUTH BRISBANE QLD AU |
| PERTH WA AU |
| NORTH PERTH WA AU |

I have been able to get the Country and State as these will never contain spaces (hopefully...), but the Suburb name may contain spaces at times.

```
DF = DF \
.withColumn("CityStateCountry", split(col("CityStateCountry"), " ")) \
.withColumn("Country", slice(col("CityStateCountry"), -1, 1)[0]) \
.withColumn("State", slice(col("CityStateCountry"), -2, 1)[0]) \
```

I was hoping to be able to slice to a specific position, rather than a length, but this doesn't seem to work. I tried the below (knowing I will also need to join these elements after extracting):

`.withColumn("Suburb", slice(col("CityStateCountry"), 1, size("CityStateCountry")-2) \`

But I get an error:

`Method slice([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column, class java.lang.Integer, class org.apache.spark.sql.Column]) does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting above is related to the function size returns a column and not a number.
The slice function expects `(org.apache.spark.sql.Column, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer)`
What you are passing to it is `(org.apache.spark.sql.Column, java.lang.Integer, org.apache.spark.sql.Column)`.

In your case I would recommend you write your own function to this using a `UDF`. The `UDF` you can create your own slice/size function to handle it using regular Scala code.

Please see the documentation [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html) and an [example](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-udfs.html)

Comment: I assumed it was a type error, is there not a way to cast the return of `size` to be `Integer`? I also attempted creating a UDF for this but got a bit stuck.